# Automatic Category assignment for received email + File name attachment

Tags: vba, outlook

I made a script to assign a category to all selected email based on some initials in the subject, some words in the body, the sender, ...

```
Public Sub autocategories()
    Dim olItem As Object
    For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        If InStr(1, olItem.Subject, "=SUB1=", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            olItem.Categories = "SUB1"
        ElseIf InStr(1, olItem.Subject, "=SUB2=", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            olItem.Categories = "SUB2"
        ElseIf InStr(1, olItem.Sender, "SEN1", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            olItem.Categories = "SEN1"
        ElseIf InStr(1, olItem.Sender, "SEN2", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            olItem.Categories = "SEN2"
        ElseIf InStr(1, olItem.Body, "BOD1", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            olItem.Categories = "BOD1"
        ElseIf InStr(1, olItem.Body, "BOD2", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            olItem.Categories = "BOD2"
        End If
        olItem.Save
    Next olItem
    Set olItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

I made a second script to assign a category automatically to all the emails sent.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal olItem As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    With olItem
        If InStr(1, olItem.Subject, "=SUB1=", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            olItem.Categories = "SUB1"
            olItem.Save
        ElseIf InStr(1, olItem.Subject, "=SUB2=", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            olItem.Categories = "SUB2"
            olItem.Save
        ElseIf InStr(1, olItem.Body, "BOD1", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            olItem.Categories = "BOD1"
            olItem.Save
        ElseIf InStr(1, olItem.Body, "BOD2", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            olItem.Categories = "BOD2"
            olItem.Save
        Else: End If
    End With
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

For the emails received:
 - I would like the assignment made automatically instead of having to select the emails and click on the macro button
-  Using the Rules is not an option as it requires an update of the key registry which is forbidden by my company.

For the email received and sent:
 - I would like to recognize the file name of an attachment
 - I tried this:

```
ElseIf InStr(1, olItem.Attachemnts, "[NAME1]", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    olItem.Categories = "[NAME1]"
    olItem.Save
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents inboxItems As Outlook.Items
Private WithEvents colSentItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim objectNS As Outlook.NameSpace

  Set outlookApp = Outlook.Application
  Set objectNS = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set inboxItems = objectNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
  Set colSentItems = objectNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items
End Sub

Private Sub inboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim MessageInfo
Dim Result
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
    'MessageInfo = "" & _
        "Sender : " & Item.SenderEmailAddress & vbCrLf & _
        "Sent : " & Item.SentOn & vbCrLf & _
        "Received : " & Item.ReceivedTime & vbCrLf & _
        "Subject : " & Item.Subject & vbCrLf & _
        "Size : " & Item.Size & vbCrLf & _
        "Message Body : " & vbCrLf & Item.Body
    'Result = MsgBox(MessageInfo, vbOKOnly, "New Message Received")

            If InStr(1, Item.Subject, "=SUB1=", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                Item.Categories = "SUB1"
            ElseIf InStr(1, Item.Subject, "=SUB2=", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                Item.Categories = "SUB2"
            ElseIf InStr(1, Item.Sender, "SEN1", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                Item.Categories = "SEN1"
            ElseIf InStr(1, Item.Sender, "SEN2", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                Item.Categories = "SEN2"
            ElseIf InStr(1, Item.Body, "BOD1", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                Item.Categories = "BOD1"
            ElseIf InStr(1, Item.Body, "BOD2", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                Item.Categories = "BOD2"
            End If
            For Each objAtt In Item.Attachments
                'objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & Item.Parent & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
                If InStr(1, objAtt.DisplayName, "[NAME1]", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    Item.Categories = "[NAME1]"
                    Item.Save
                End If
                Set objAtt = Nothing
            Next
            Item.Save
End If
ExitNewItem:
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume ExitNewItem
End Sub



Private Sub colSentItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    If Item.Class = olMail Then
       'Item.ShowCategoriesDialog
        If InStr(1, Item.Subject, "=SUB1=", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Item.Categories = "SUB1"
        ElseIf InStr(1, Item.Subject, "=SUB2=", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Item.Categories = "SUB2"
        ElseIf InStr(1, Item.Body, "BOD1", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Item.Categories = "BOD1"
        ElseIf InStr(1, Item.Body, "BOD2", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Item.Categories = "BOD2"
        End If
        Item.Save
    End If
End Sub
```

Attachments

```
For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
    objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & itm.Parent & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
Next
```

Comment: No need for outlookApp , code is already in Outlook- simply use Application

Comment: What do you mean "use Application"?

Comment: Hey, sorry but the code doesn't work.
I copy pasted it in "ThisOutlookSession" and updated with what I needed but no result.
Can you just tell me, with my initial script how to add a line so it can recognize the file name attachement? That would help! Thanks

Comment: item.Attachments(0).DisplayName

Comment: Like this?
`ElesIf InStr(1, olItem.Attachments(0).DisplayName, "example", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            olItem.Categories = "CAT1" `

Comment: What I would like actually, is that my first script recognize the name attachment and assign a category based on it. 
How should I include it?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following -

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Inbox  As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set Items = Inbox.Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        autocategories Item
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub autocategories(ByVal olItem As Object)
        If InStr(1, olItem.Subject, "=SUB1=", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            olItem.Categories = "SUB1"
        ElseIf InStr(1, olItem.Subject, "=SUB2=", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            olItem.Categories = "SUB2"
        ElseIf InStr(1, olItem.Sender, "SEN1", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            olItem.Categories = "SEN1"
        ElseIf InStr(1, olItem.Sender, "SEN2", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            olItem.Categories = "SEN2"
        ElseIf InStr(1, olItem.body, "BOD1", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            olItem.Categories = "BOD1"
        ElseIf InStr(1, olItem.body, "BOD2", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            olItem.Categories = "BOD2"
        End If
        olItem.Save
    Set olItem = Nothing
End Sub


Private Sub TestMsg()
    Dim olMsg As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olMsg = ActiveExplorer.selection.Item(1)
    FwdItem olMsg
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for your comment. Actually what I would like s that my first script recognize the name attachment and assign a category based on it. How should I include it? So something like included in the first code I wrote: 

ElseIf InStr(1, Atmt.FileName, "example", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then olItem.Categories = "CAT1"

It is really important for me to keep the same Macro button so I can sort email based subject, body, sender and file name attachement. Automation is not that important